# Consume SOAP API that returns JSON data using ColdFusion

Tags: json, api, soap, coldfusion

I was given a URL that is supposed to return some JSON data which contains a oAuth Token to access the rest of the API. The API call uses GET and it contains the username and password in the URL.

**When I try accessing the API's URL I get the following message:**

```
error   unauthorized
error_description   An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
```

**Below is an example of my ColdFusion:**

```
<CFHTTP URL="https://test-ows01.website.com/data_api//1.0/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=HelloWorld&password=MyPassword!" method="GET" result="result">
</CFHTTP>

<cfset content = deserializeJSON(result.filecontent.toString())>

<cfdump var="#content#">
```

**Other info:** When I drop the URL (it is not the correct URL for this questions) into a browser I get the “Log In” prompt and after I enter the username: HelloWorld and the password: MyPassword! I am then taken to a page that shows the JSON data which contained the oAuth Token among other data.

I was given a SOAPUI file so review how the API works so if there is some other info I need to provide I may be able to pull it from there.

Comment: If my question is going to be down voted please leave a comment with what  I left out or whatever was the reason for the down vote. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not seeing a soap envelope being sent to the URL, so you may not be working with the soap endpoint of the web service. Given the login prompt, request may require basic authentication as well.

Comment: *may require basic authentication as well* ... ie Instead of passing the username and password as URL parameters, try using the "username" and "password" attributes of cfhttp.

Comment: The last two comments are correct. I spoke with the other developer and he confirmed there will need to be a basic authentication before the API can be called.

Comment: Leigh you were correct all I had to do was include the username and password parameters in the cfhttp tag and I was able to connect successfully. If you want to answer I will check it as completed.

Comment: Denoteone - Thanks, but I was just elaborating on @Twillen's suggestion about basic authentication (as I am pretty sure that is what they meant :) If it solved the problem, Twillen should post it as an "answer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server your connecting to is requiring authentication credentials during in the request. Add the username and password to the `cfhttp` tag to send the credentials within the request.

```
<cfhttp  url="example.com/data_api//1.0/oauth/token?grant_type=password" method="GET" result="result" 
    username="HelloWorld" password="MyPassword!">
</cfhttp>
```

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I was looking for. +1 Checked.